# Is there a way to write to Kiba CSV destination line by line or in batches instead of all at once?

Tags: kiba-etl

Kiba is really cool!

I'm trying to set up a ETL process in my Rails app where I'll dump a large amount of data from my SQL DB to a CSV file. If I were to implement this myself I'd use something like `find_each` to load say 1000 records at a time and write them to the file in batches. Is there a way to do this using Kiba? From my understanding by default all of the `rows` from the Source get passed to the Destination, which wouldn't be feasible for my situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glad you like Kiba!

I'm going to make you happy by stating that your understanding is incorrect.

The rows are yielded & processed one by one in Kiba.

To see how things work exactly, I suggest you try it this code:

```rb
class MySource
  def initialize(enumerable)
    @enumerable = enumerable
  end

  def each
    @enumerable.each do |item|
      puts "Source is reading #{item}"
      yield item
    end
  end
end

class MyDestination
  def write(row)
    puts "Destination is writing #{row}"
  end
end

source MySource, (1..10)
destination MyDestination
```

Run this and you'll see that each item is read then written.

Now to your actual concrete case - what's above means that you can implement your source this way:

```rb
class ActiveRecord
  def initialize(model:)
    @model = model
  end

  def each
    @model.find_each do |record|
      yield record
    end
  end
end
```

then you can use it like this:

```rb
source ActiveRecordSource, model: Person.where("age > 21")
```

(You could also leverage `find_in_batches` if you wanted each row to be an array of multiple records, but that's probably not what you need here).

Hope this properly answers your question!

Comment: Thanks! Clearly I made a bad assumption. I really appreciate you taking the time to clear that up.